# How do I deny log on through Terminal Services (RDP) from a command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, administration

In Windows 2003, I can start... 
**Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Local Security Policy** 
Then, if I go to... 
 
**Local Policies -> User  Rights Assignment -> Deny log on through Terminal Services** 
... it lets me deny RDP access to a certain user account (even if that account is an admin).

How can I do the same thing from the command line, so I can automate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `reg` command to modify the registry key that corresponds to this group policy setting.

To disable, try this from a batch file:

```
reg ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server"
/v fDenyTSConnections
/t REG_DWORD
/d 1
/f
```

I've wrapped the switches onto multiple lines for readability, make sure to put all that on one line in your batch file.  I don't have access to a Windows 2003 server to confirm those two settings are one in the same but I believe they are.  You could use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to watch which registry key changes when you change that GP setting to sniff out which one it is in the event that I have the wrong key.

It appears you can also change this using the [NTRights Utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315276) and the `SeDenyRemoteInteractiveLogonRight` right.  The syntax for that would be:

```
NTRights.exe -u user +r SeDenyRemoteInteractiveLogonRight
```

Comment: Nice! NTRights.exe doesn't list that policy in its usage, so I missed it. You have to use +r though, not -r (since it's DENYING a right). However, that worked great.

Comment: Excellent, glad it worked.  Thanks for clearing that up too, I updated the post to use `+r` instead.